# Hide anchors using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

I've created a dynamic page that, depending on the view type, will sometimes utilize the anchor tags and other times not.  Essentially, I want to be able to control if on click the page jumps to the anchor.  Is it possible to hide anchor tags using jQUery, so they are essentially removed?  I need to be able to re-enable the anchors when necessary, and always show the current anchor in the browser's address bar.  It seems to work in FireFox, but not in Internet Explorer.

I have three sections: the 'table of contents', the content, and the javascript (jQuery) code

**Table of Contents**

```
<a id="expandLink0" class="expandLinksList" href="#green">What is green purchasing</a><br>
<a id="expandLink1" class="expandLinksList" href="#before">Before you buy</a><br>
```

**Contents**

```
<ul id="makeIntoSlideshowUL">'
<li id="slideNumber0" class="slideShowSlide">
    <a name="green"></a>
    <div>Green Purchasing refers to the procurement of products and service...<a href="#topOfPageAnchor" class="topOfPageAnchorClass">Back to Top</a></div>
</li>
<li id="slideNumber1" class="slideShowSlide">
    <a name="before"></a>
    <div>We easily accomplish the first four bullet points under...<a href="#topOfPageAnchor" class="topOfPageAnchorClass">Back to Top</a></div>
</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery On Page Load**

```
$(".slideShowSlide").each(function() {
$(this).children(":first-child").hide();
});
```

**jQuery to re-enable links**

```
$(".slideShowSlide").each(function() {
$(this).children(":first-child").show();
});
```

I've also tried prepending an extra character to all anchor names to 'disable' them, but IE won't change the names using attr("name").  The only real manipulation it's letting me do is remove().

Comment: If your question involves DOM selection, you really need to provide an example of the markup that's being selected.

Comment: @patrick, I hope this is enough for the example.

Comment: What do you get when you do `alert($(".slideShowSlide > a:first-child").length);`? What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I get '10', both in IE and FireFox.  I'm using jQuery 1.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way:

```
$(".slideShowSlide").each(function() {
    $(this).children().first().hide();
});
```

Or even this way:

```
$(".slideShowSlide").each(function() {
    $(this).children(':first').hide();
});
```

Comment: Also, Eric Bari, you should really use a toggle. Keep things DRY :)